# Restfullyii prepending <link> tag to the json response

Tags: json, rest, yii

Hi I'm new to restfulyii

I'm having a problem with the json response a  tag is being prepended
Refer to the code below
(just assume that there are '<>' for the link tag)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/e5ba1689/srbac.css" />{"success":true,"message":"Record(s) Found","data":{"totalCount":1,"share":[{"id":"0","elementid":"1","type":"video","suid":"1","duid":"5","permissions":"superuser"}]}}
```

this coming from api/ under GET method and same with other rest verbs

I can't parse my JSON data because of the prepended line.

Please help..

reference:
localhost/api/ - method: GET/POST/PUT/DELETE

Everything is working fine with restful yii except that json response format...

Thanks in advance!
Ohmel Paguirigan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seams to be that YII is not recognizing that your request is an actual Ajax request.

Search in srbac/components/Helper.php for:

`if (!Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
   Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($cssFile);
}`

You will notice that SRBAC is checking if your request is an actual Ajax request.
[Yoshi](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/4945-yiiapp-request-isajaxrequest/page__view__findpost__p__26462) on the Yii Forms says that:

> yii checks if there is a X-Requested-With HTTP header set (which
>   should result in an $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] server variable)
>   and whether it contains the string 'XMLHttpRequest'. But this is a
>   custom header set by most javascript libraries (and so does jQuery).
>   There are e.g. some proxies which drop these custom headers (mainly
>   for security reasons) and therefore your application can't recognize
>   whether it's an ajax request or not. It's not 100% reliable.

Therefore, you must make sure that your javascript library is injecting this Header.
To do this in Javascript, in your app.run
add the following:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Then, all of y our http requests in angular will send the header yii needs to discern that an AjaxRequest is being sent!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer....
I thought that Yii is pretty much handling isAjaxRequest and will detect it everytime I use $.http()

this works thanks!

Comment: `$http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';` works nice for me. Thanks.